# how i stay selected when i back from another activtity (playing Activity)

Tags: java, listview, android-arrayadapter

this `MainActivity` data
          i have multiple data in listview round about 100 data in list so my question is when I click on the first item in listview and it goes to another activity and then i back from this activity to listview its fine that its show from first but when I click on middle or last item in listview it goes to another activity when I back from this activity to listview activity it show me data from first so how I stay selected on item in listview when coming from back activity ?

```
final ArrayList<Data> datas = new ArrayList<Data>();

       datas.add(new Data("ye_dosti",R.drawable.icons,R.raw.ye_dosti));
        datas.add(new Data("ya_banday_mitti_k_banday",R.drawable.icons,R.raw.ya_banday_mitti_k_banday));
        datas.add(new Data("aey_rah_e_haq_kay_shahido",R.drawable.icons,R.raw.aey_rah_e_haq_kay_shahido));
        datas.add(new Data("aye_mard_e_mujahid",R.drawable.icons,R.raw.aye_mard_e_mujahid));
        datas.add(new Data("aye_wattan_pyare_watten",R.drawable.icons,R.raw.aye_wattan_pyare_watten));
 final dataAdapter adapter = new dataAdapter(this, datas);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

                try {
                    if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                        mInterstitialAd.show();
                    } else {
                        Data data =datas.get(position);
                        String text=data.getText().toLowerCase();
                        int audioid=data.getmAudioResource();
                        Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,playerActivtiy.class);
                        intent.putExtra(clickvalue,text);
                        intent.putExtra(audiovalue,audioid);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                    mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdClosed() {
                            requestNewInterstitial();
                            Data data =datas.get(position);
                            String text=data.getText().toLowerCase();
                            int audioid=data.getmAudioResource();
                            Intent intent =new Intent(MainActivity.this,playerActivtiy.class);
                            intent.putExtra(clickvalue,text);
                            intent.putExtra(audiovalue,audioid);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        }
                    });
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

List item

dataAdapter 
   so   how  i back to  position on which i clicked  Mainactivity

```
 public class dataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Data> {
        Data currentword;
        public dataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Data> data) {
            super(context, 0,data);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return super.getCount();
        }

        @Override
        public Data getItem(int position) {
            return super.getItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return super.getItemId(position);
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(int position,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View list_item=convertView;
            if(list_item == null){
                list_item = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.listitems, parent, false);
            }
            currentword= getItem(position);
            TextView texts=(TextView)  list_item.findViewById(R.id.text);
            texts.setText(currentword.getText());
            texts.setTag(position);
            ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) list_item.findViewById(R.id.images);
            mImageView.setImageResource(currentword.getImageId());
            mImageView.setTag(position);
            list_item.setTag(position);
            return list_item;
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store the position of the last clicked item in the fragment of activity. Then when navigating back to that activity you can set the position on the listview like this:

```
listView.smoothScrollToPosition()
```

Comment: you mean that i store position of itemclick and send it another activity  through intent  and then back to this activity  and store in this method just like that listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position)

Comment: @AlSadiqInsitute yeah or you can just keep the position in the activity

Comment: adapter = new dataAdapter(this, datas);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(comeback);

Comment: but listView.smoothScrollToPosition(comeback)  is not scroll to that position   even the value is store in comeback        like    i debug and see  comeback  = 18 etc  but it did not scroll plz any suggestion

Comment: bro thanks  its work on this code i found it   //adapter = new dataAdapter(this, datas);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        int h1=listView.getHeight();
        listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(comeback,h1,2);
        listView.smoothScrollToPosition(comeback,0);
        listView.setSelection(comeback);

Answer (score 0):

thank God after long struggle i found this and this work fine   just that code

```
adapter = new dataAdapter(this, datas);
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    int h1=listView.getHeight();
    listView.smoothScrollToPositionFromTop(comeback,h1,2);
    listView.smoothScrollToPosition(comeback,0);
    listView.setSelection(comeback);
```